# InteliJ Idea and OS X use different Java directories

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, sdkman

I've installed "SDK man" to use OpenJDK distributes. I set 'java_home' as my `/.sdkman/candidates/java/current` dir. But Intelij Idea uses `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home` instead of the first one.
I've already added `JAVA_HOME` variable as a path to `sdk/current` to my `bash.profile` and `~/.zsh` file, but it hasn't helped.
How to fix it?

Comment: Do you understand that IntelliJ can use one JVM to run itself while using a different JVM to run your app? IntelliJ comes with a JVM to run itself. You need not change that.

Comment: `But Intelij Idea uses /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home instead of the first one` What will it use if you change the `current` JDK and restart the IDE?